# Rename columns in data frame in R using lookup data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with the default column names V1, V2, V3, V230, etc.

I have another data frame which has 2 columns, one containing V1, V2, V3 etc and the second column containing a character string.

I would like to rename the columns in the forst data frame using the second data frame as a lookup table.

Note that the first data frame has less columns than are listed in the second "lookup" data frame.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match`

```
colnames(firstdat) <- seconddat[,2][match(colnames(firstdat), 
                      seconddat[,1], nomatch=0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Say the first data frame is `x` and second one is `y`:

```
colnames(x) <- merge(data.frame(colnames(x)), y, by.x ="colnames.x.", by.y= "Col1" )[,2]

### Col1 is the name of column 1 of *y* (containing V1, V2 etc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
temp.lookup <- lookup[lookup$oldnames %in% names(DT), ]
setnames(DT, old = temp.lookup$oldnames, new = temp.lookup$newnames)
```